# How to use map with several arguments - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Use map with several arguments?

**Something like *foldr* or *foldl*?**

Comment: `map (func arg1 arg2) charList`

Comment: Please show a sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 5):

If the other arguments are fixed, do a partial application. E.g.:

```
map (func arg1 arg2) your_list
```

Answer (score 3):

Haskell supports *partial application*, which means you can pass only a few arguments into a function, and you will get out a function which takes the rest of the arguments.

For example, I can take an expression like:

`map (\x -> x*x) [1,2,3,4]`

and rewrite it as:

`let mapsquare = map (\x -> x*x) in mapsquare [1,2,3,4]`

In the above case, I've taken the partially applied map, and assigning it to a variable, and then using that function of one argument on a list.

In your example, you could write `let f = func str1 str2 in map f charls`, or `map (func str1 str2) charls`.